# Android making duplicate .dex files of apk's in dalvik-cache

Tags: android, android-source, dalvik

I am developing a product based on Android AOSP 4.4.2 running on custom hardware. I have a separate partition `/opt` and my apk's are stored in `/opt/harsh/app/` . I also have a symlink `/vendor` which points to `/opt/harsh` (this is required as per the design structure).

The issue I'm facing is that there are multiple .dex files created in `/data/dalvik-cache` for `/opt/harsh/app/*.apk` and `/vendor/app/*.apk` which are the same files, but both of these set of .dex files have different user groups. Because of this my applications are not running properly. If I make change to not create `/opt` partition and only create `/vendor` partition instead of symlink and put apk's in it, everything works fine.

Pls help ...

Comment: It's not creating duplicate DEX files, it's creating one DEX file per APK.  The problem is that you have multiple APKs.  What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: Yes I have multiple APKs but ideally it should not scan /opt/harsh directory . We had older device working on Android 2.3 and it only scanned /system and /vendor directories. We are in process of porting Android 4.4 and facing this issue on it. The problem because of this multiple APKs is that some applications are crashing by throwing exception of Unable to instantiate ComponentInfo / Class not found.

Comment: @fadden : Also worth noting here is that, if I don't create the /vendor symlink then it doesn't create DEX for /opt/harsh/app directory even if the APKs are there. But if I create symlink then DEX are created for /vendor/app and /opt/harsh/app both !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the issue myself !

There is a bug in libcore/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexFile.java which caused this issue. Here in this function :

```
private static int openDexFile(String sourceName, String outputName,
    int flags) throws IOException {
    return openDexFileNative(new File(sourceName).getCanonicalPath(),
                             (outputName == null) ? null : new File(outputName).getCanonicalPath(),
                             flags);
}
```

The issue is in `new File(sourceName).getCanonicalPath()`

By changing it to `new File(sourceName).getAbsolutePath()` the issue is solved